# MKMapView userLocation showing 0,0 in simulator?

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a mapView outlet on my view (MKMapViewDelegate) with "Shows user location" enabled.

In the viewdidload for that controller I have

```
CLLocation *userLoc = mapView.userLocation.location;
CLLocationCoordinate2D userCoordinate = userLoc.coordinate;
NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userCoordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userCoordinate.longitude); 
mapView.delegate=self;
```

The simulator shows the correct user location on the map (I'm using Custom location in the IOS Simulator)

But the NSLog shows 0 and 0 for latitude and longitude.

Shouldn't I be able to get the custom longitude and latitude in the simulator?

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER:**

Needed to implement

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    self.mapView.centerCoordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Location services aren't instantaneous.  Your code is in `viewDidLoad`, so it hasn't had a chance to get a fix on your position yet.  You should set the `delegate` property for the map view to an object that implements the `MKMapViewDelegate` protocol.

Comment: Can you provide maybe some sample code?   I did set the mapview delegate to self in the code above?   I'd like the maps initial zoom location to be based off the user's current location

Comment: Did you implement any of the `MKMapViewDelegate` methods?  Setting the delegate won't do a thing unless you implement methods that it defines.  There are several map sample projects in the developer centre.  Have you looked at them?

Comment: Couldn't find sample code for this on Apple's site.   Would love to find a sample project that does this

Comment: You need to implement `didUpdateUserLocation`.  There should be numerous examples on this site as well as on Apple's.

Comment: There's a link that says "Sample Code" on the iOS Dev Center homepage.  If you click it, it gives you a list of all the sample code Apple has.  There's a search box, and if you put "map" in it, it gives you eight sample projects that use MapKit.

Answer (score 0):

```
MKMapView *mapview=[[MKMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300, 364)];
mapview.delegate=self;
mapview.showsUserLocation=YES;
```

Which then will call the mapkit delegate, in the mak kit delegate try to print the coordinates.
NSLog(@"user latitude = %f",userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude);
NSLog(@"user longitude = %f",userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude);

Answer (score 0):

I had to set a location in the simulator, via Debug > Location. It was set to None, which dumped me at (0°, 0°) and never updated; you can set a Custom Location or choose from other simulated location scripts that move the user location automatically over time.